# $(...).slider is not a function

Tags: jsp, java-8, jspdf, jstl

Hola por favor necesito su ayuda, tengo un problema no me muestra en mi vista jsp la lista de los productos recomendados, he podido registrar productos al servidor desde el formulario sin ningún problema, pero al momento de tratar de listar los productos recomendados no logra pintar en mi jsp.
He leído en foros que ya no es necesario adjuntar la uri `<%@ taglib uri = "http://java.sun.com/jsp/jstl/core" prefix = "c" %>`, pues solo basta con agregar la librería JSTL, sin embargo aún así no me pinta la información que deseo, muchas gracias¡¡¡

Bean Producto:

```
public class Producto {
    
    private int webid;
    private String nombre;
    private float precio;
    private float precionuevo;
    private int stock;
    private boolean nuevo;
    private boolean recomendado;
    private boolean visible;
    private String descripcion;
    private int codigo_marca;
    private int codigo_categoria;
    private String img;

    public Producto() {
    }

    public int getWebid() {
        return webid;
    }

    public void setWebid(int webid) {
        this.webid = webid;
    }

    public String getNombre() {
        return nombre;
    }

    public void setNombre(String nombre) {
        this.nombre = nombre;
    }

    public float getPrecio() {
        return precio;
    }

    public void setPrecio(float precio) {
        this.precio = precio;
    }

    public float getPrecionuevo() {
        return precionuevo;
    }

    public void setPrecionuevo(float precionuevo) {
        this.precionuevo = precionuevo;
    }

    public int getStock() {
        return stock;
    }

    public void setStock(int stock) {
        this.stock = stock;
    }

    public boolean isNuevo() {
        return nuevo;
    }

    public void setNuevo(boolean nuevo) {
        this.nuevo = nuevo;
    }

    public boolean isRecomendado() {
        return recomendado;
    }

    public void setRecomendado(boolean recomendado) {
        this.recomendado = recomendado;
    }

    public boolean isVisible() {
        return visible;
    }

    public void setVisible(boolean visible) {
        this.visible = visible;
    }

    public String getDescripcion() {
        return descripcion;
    }

    public void setDescripcion(String descripcion) {
        this.descripcion = descripcion;
    }

    public int getCodigo_marca() {
        return codigo_marca;
    }

    public void setCodigo_marca(int codigo_marca) {
        this.codigo_marca = codigo_marca;
    }

    public int getCodigo_categoria() {
        return codigo_categoria;
    }

    public void setCodigo_categoria(int codigo_categoria) {
        this.codigo_categoria = codigo_categoria;
    }

    public String getImg() {
        return img;
    }

    public void setImg(String img) {
        this.img = img;
    }
    
}
```

Meotodo para recibir los datos:

```
private void recibirDatos(HttpServletRequest request){
        try {
            FileItemFactory fileFactory=new DiskFileItemFactory();            
            ServletFileUpload servletUpload=new ServletFileUpload(fileFactory);            
            String nombre="";
            List items=servletUpload.parseRequest(request);
            for(int i=0;i<items.size();i++){
                FileItem item=(FileItem) items.get(i);
                if(!item.isFormField()){
                    String ruta=request.getServletContext().getRealPath("/")+"foto/";
                    SimpleDateFormat sdf=new SimpleDateFormat("ddMyyyyhhmmss");
                    String fecha=sdf.format(new Date());
                    nombre=fecha+new Random().nextLong()+item.getName();
                    String nuevonombre=ruta+nombre;
                    File folder=new File(ruta);
                    if(!folder.exists()){
                        folder.mkdirs();
                    }
                    File imagen=new File(nuevonombre);
                    if(item.getContentType().contains("image")){
                        item.write(imagen);
                        request.setAttribute(item.getFieldName(), nombre);
                    }
                }else{
                    request.setAttribute(item.getFieldName(), item.getString());
                }
            }
        } catch (FileUploadException ex) {
           request.setAttribute("subida", false);
        } catch (Exception ex) {
            request.setAttribute("subida", false);
        }
        
    }
```

Metodo para listar productos recomendados:

```
public static ArrayList<Producto> listarProductosRecomendados(String moneda){
        try {
            String sql="{call sp_listarRecomendados(?)}";
            Connection c=Conexion.conectar();
            CallableStatement sentencia=  (CallableStatement) c.prepareCall(sql);
            sentencia.setString(1, moneda);

            ResultSet res= sentencia.executeQuery();
            ArrayList<Producto> lista=new ArrayList<>();
            while(res.next())/*MIENTRAS VALLA ENCONTRANDO REGISTRO... QUE REALICE :*/{
                Producto p=new Producto();
                p.setWebid(res.getInt("webid"));
                p.setNombre(res.getString("nombre"));
                p.setImg(res.getString("img"));
                p.setStock(res.getInt("stock"));
                p.setNuevo(res.getBoolean("nuevo"));
                if(!moneda.equalsIgnoreCase("MXN")){
                    p.setPrecio(res.getFloat("precio2"));
                    p.setPrecionuevo(res.getFloat("precion2"));
                }else{
                    p.setPrecio(res.getFloat("precio"));
                    p.setPrecionuevo(res.getFloat("precionuevo"));
                }
                lista.add(p);
            }
            return lista;
        } catch (SQLException ex) {
            return null;
        } 
    }
```

La vista jsp:

```
<c:forEach var ="p" items="<%=ProductoCad.listarProductosRecomendados(session.getAttribute("moneda").toString())%>">
                        <div class="col-sm-4">
                            <div class="product-image-wrapper">
                                <div class="single-products">
                                        <div class="productinfo text-center">
                                            <img src="foto/${p.img}" alt=""/>
                                                                                        <h2>${sessionScope.moneda}${p.precio}</h2>
                                            <p>${p.nombre}</p>
                                            <span class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Agregar al carrito</span>
                                        </div>
                                        <div class="product-overlay">
                                            <div class="overlay-content">
                                                <h2>${sessionScope.moneda}${p.precio}</h2>
                                                <p>${p.nombre}</p>
                                                <a href="#" class="btn btn-default add-to-cart"><i class="fa fa-shopping-cart"></i>Agregar al carrito</a>
                                            </div>
                                        </div>
                                </div>
                                <div class="choose">
                                    <ul class="nav nav-pills nav-justified">
                                        <li><a href=""><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i><i class="fa fa-star"></i></a></li>
                                        <li><a href="#"><i class="fa fa-check-circle"></i>Disponible</a></li>
                                    </ul>
                                </div>
                            </div>
                        </div>                                              
                                                </c:forEach>
```

Puedo ver por consola que muestra un error al tratar de llamar a la foto:
[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

Comment: Bienvenido a SOe. Estaría bien que añadieras algún log a tu código para ver qué valor devuelve *Producto.getImg()* y detectar si el problema está en el JSP o en la recuperación de datos. También estaría bien que especificaras tu entorno, lo de "ahora no es necesario hacer X" depende de la versión que estés usando. En todo caso, si suponemos que "MXN" en la imagen se corresponde a `<p>${p.nombre}</p>`, entonces parece que el *c:forEach* está funcionando bien.

Comment: Para futuras preguntas te sería de ayuda hacer un [mcve] que simplifique el código que muestras.